# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'any'. Dealing with object that will have attribute, Python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, attributeerror, nonetype

I am trying to identify Aruco markers in an image. Initially the markers will be undetectable and may become undetectable during. The issue is in my if statement, ids, doesn't exist yet. So if I check any I get an error saying it has no type. Once I find it this error goes away. I'm not sure of a good way to handle this situation.

```
    grey_im  = cv2.cvtColor(image_np, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    (corners, ids, rejected) = cv2.aruco.detectMarkers(grey_im, self.alg.ARUCO_DICT, parameters=self.alg.ARUCO_PARAMS)
    
    if (ids.any() != 0):
        cnt = 0

        for id in ids:
```

*File "/home/me/WorkDir/Mothership/src/mothership.py", line 184, in locateAruco
if (ids.any() != 0):
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'any'*

Which is the error I get before any aruco markers are detected.

Comment: You can check if ids is None

Comment: Thanks, haven't done a lot in python lately. That's what I was looking for.